# Query string comes between my domain and controller address in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and have a form that the action address loads with AngularJS.

When I submit the form the `q` value goes between my domain and my controller address, something like this:

```
http://localhost/?q=test#/en/search/


<li>
  <form action="{{'/#/'+ Page.Culture + '/search'}}">
    <input type="text" name="q" ><button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</li>
```

Why is that?

Comment: what way do you expect your url to look?

Comment: What does `{{'/#/'+ Page.Culture + '/search'}}` evaluate?

Comment: I expect my url to look like  http://localhost/#/en/search/?q=test

Comment: Because of this issue I cant access my q variable using $location.search().q and it works only when it's in the right structure

Comment: the final address that it generates is /#/en/search

Answer (score 0):

Are you using hash routing on purpose? The query string position is correct for hash routing URLs - everything after `#` is client-side only and not sent to server, unlike query string parameters. Thus, the URL becomes `http://locahost/?q=test#/en/search` when browser submits the form.

Angular can put together an URL where also `q` is after the hash as [shown in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#example):

```
$location.path('/new').search('x=y');
$location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/new?x=y'
```

but you apparently allow the browser to submit the form and it will not construct URI like that because the server would not receive the parameter `q` at all.

You could catch the submit event and route manually to have nicer hashbang URI, or you could switch to HTML5 mode to have prettier URLs. This requires little backend support as well, namely that you will send the index HTML page from any requested URL apart from your specific API endpoints. See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode) for more information.